# shell - display number of errors for best matches in agrep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, agrep

What I am trying to do is to get the best-matching word in a file and the number of errors for it using `agrep`. For now I am only able to get the word using this script:

```
array=(bla1 bla2 bla3)
for eachWord in "${array[@]}"; do
  result=$(yes "yes" | agrep -B ${eachWord} /home/victoria/file.txt)
  printf "$result\n"
done
```

Where *bla{1,2,3}* are some words.

The output I have is the following:

```
agrep: 4 words match within 2 errors; search for them? (y/n)counting
first
and
should
agrep: 1 word matches within 1 error; search for it? (y/n)should
agrep: 2 words match within 4 errors; search for them? (y/n)must
must
agrep: 1 word matches within 2 errors; search for it? (y/n)should
```

Is there any way I can have the number of errors (*2,1,4,2* in the output example above)?

Comment: What do you want with it?

Comment: the Levenstein distance for mine and the best-matching word

Comment: As far as i've understood, you want the output to be: 2 1 4 2(i.e, number of errors). Can you try this: `result=$(yes "yes" | agrep -B ${eachWord} /home/victoria/file.txt|sed -E -n 's/.*\s+within\s+([0-9]+)\s+errors\;.*/\1/p')`. I'm pretty sure,this can be done using one `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: What I get after this is the following. Is there a way to extract only the second number? : agrep: 4 words match within 2 errors; search for them? (y/n)
agrep: 1 word matches within 1 error; search for it? (y/n)
agrep: 2 words match within 4 errors; search for them? (y/n)
agrep: 1 word matches within 2 errors; search for it? (y/n)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that `agrep` reports the errors to standard error (file descriptor 2) and not to standard out (file descriptor 1). In order to throw away stdout and return stderr, you have to redirect stdout to /dev/null and redirect stderr to stdout:

```
2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

The minor problem is, that `agrep` does not output proper line endings, if you feed it by `yes`. You have to write a newline it stderr:

```
echo >&2
```

Finally, as [User123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8001873/user123) told you, you need a `sed` command to extract the number of errors.

This is an example:

```
for a in r1234t rot ruht rood; do
  yes y | agrep -B "$a" /etc/passwd
  echo >&2
done 2>&1 1>/dev/null |
sed -n 's/.* \([0-9]\+\) error.*/\1/p'
```

Output is:

```
4
1
2
1
```

Comment: I guess the OP only wants the second number (i.e more precisely, the number of errors: the number before the string 'errorrs'), so `sed` command could be modified a bit: `'s/.*\s+within\s+([0-9]+)\s+errors\;.*/\1/p'`